# How to pass DataFrame of python pyspark to Dataset of Java function

Tags: python, java, dataframe, pyspark, dataset

I am trying to call java function from python pyspark by passing dataframe as one of the arguments. But I get "'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'" error.

Can anyone please help me in solving it.

I have tried below code

```
def call_java_method(spark, sc, df):
    df = spark.read \
        .format("csv") \
        .option("header", "false") \
        .option("delimiter", "|").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", 'true') \
        .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", 'true').load("resources/data_success.txt")
    df1 = df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView('databas')
    df1.show()
    df1.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    
    java_import(sc._jvm, "en.test.data")
    func = sc._jvm.data()
    func.add(spark._jsparkSession, df1, 1, [2])
```

Result:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Expected:
call below java function from pyspark python

```
public void add(SparkSession spark, Dataset<Row> baseDataset, int count, List<Integer> keys) throws InputDataException {...}
```

data_success.txt

374314019059271||||||||||||||||26.666666667|-833.2904092||0|Ineligible for Training
374314019184053||||||||||||||||21.083333333|0.3704427414|10|64|Ineligible for Rev

Comment: If you want to use java udf function in your pyspark code then you can follow this recipe : https://gist.github.com/dineshdharme/2e7b8fa839b67acc42c83fa542062cfa  . But if you want to pass your python rdd to a java function which operations on RDD then you need to first convert python rdd into java rdd and then operate as shown in this recipe. https://gist.github.com/dineshdharme/81b56fd1867954faa0d4912eda30f7a0